# Embedded Google Map only showing for a specific position in the DOM?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having an odd situation using the Google Maps API. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

Users can upload photos to my website. These may have Geo tag info their EXIF, which I read. If they have it, I'd like to show a small embedded map to the side of the image.

The problem is that I can get the map to show when I place the map canvas element directly under body, but not anywhere else. Here's an example of the map working:

http://ferdy.dnsalias.com/apps/jungledragon/image/3/leaf.html

This is a temp URL to my dev environment. Don't mind the broken page layout, this is just a tech test to prove that the map code I'm using is functional, it even takes the actual coordinates into account.

So in that URL, the map canvas element is position directly under `<body>`:

```
<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 50%; height: 50%"></div>
```

As you can see, that works. But that's not where I want the embedded map to appear, it should be here in the DOM:

```
<html>-><body>-><div id="wrapper">-><div id="content"><aside>->map canvas here
```

Basically, I want it in the sidebar. However, when I move the canvas div element there, nothing shows. I've tried a few placed in the DOM and it seems very sensitive about where in the nesting the canvas element is.

Not sure if it helps, but my layout approach realizes a "sticky" footer.

**Update:** I figured out that when I place the map canvas div anywhere inside my #wrapper div, it does not work, but it does work outside of it. It doesn't solve my problem yet because I need that wrapper div, also I cannot figure out why it would block the rendering, here's the CSS of the wrapper div:

```
#wrapper { display:block;width: 960px; margin:0 auto;min-height: 100%;overflow:auto; }
```

Even if I disable all the CSS declaration of this wrapper, it still does not render the map. Mystery!

Comment: If the parent dom element (in this case <aside>) is display != block the map won't appear. Make sure <aside> is recognized by your browser.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along, but aside does have display:block; It is at the top of my stylesheet, and I'm using HTML shiv for IE. I have double checked in Firebug and it does see it as a block element.

Comment: If you put the map directly in <aside> it works. But if the map is in any of the children of <aside>, it doesn't.

Comment: Really? I cannot reproduce that. When I put it directly below aside it still does not render anything. How have you tested this?

Comment: I did this: <aside id="map_canvas1" style="width:80%; height:100%; float:left"></aside>

Comment: Sorry but I still cannot reproduce it. Here's a seperate test page with your suggestion included: http://ferdy.dnsalias.com/apps/jungledragon/home/simple Still no map :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, and it was embarassingly simple:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Rather than using a percentage-based width, switching to absolute sizes fixed everything.